# What to do when stable packages have unstable dependencies?

Tags: apt

I have some packages that `apt` is purposefully holding back. Here's a sample of what I'm seeing:

```
> apt update
...
<error-free list of all my repos being fetched>
...
Fetched 88.7 kB in 4s (22.7 kB/s)                   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
9 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

> apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  fontconfig fontconfig-config ghostscript-x libfontconfig1-dev libgs9-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

My usual approach to fix this is to start explicitly listing the packages that are held back so I get better output telling me why the package was held back. Using this approach, I believe that there are 2 different groups of held back packages: the `libfontconfig1` group and the `libfreetype6` group.

For example, when I try to upgrade `fontconfig` and `fontconfig-config`:

```
> apt upgrade fontconfig fontconfig-config
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fontconfig : Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.13.0) but 2.12.6-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 fontconfig-config : Breaks: libfontconfig1 (< 2.13.0) but 2.12.6-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

What am I supposed to do when it simultaneously wants `libfontconfig1` greater than or equal to 2.13.0 but also it must be less than 2.13.0?

The `libfreetype6` bundle of packages are slightly different:

```
> apt upgrade ghostscript-x libfontconfig1-dev libgs9-common ghostscript libgs9 libfontconfig1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfontconfig1 : Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.9.1) but 2.8.1-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libgs9 : Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.10.1) but 2.8.1-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Here, I get a paragraph that explains the situation but I don't have a course of action for how to respond to it. It appears that libfreetype6 2.10 is still in the unstable repo. I would really like to avoid adding an unstable repo to my machine. This feels like a problem that will go away as soon as 2.10 is stable.

These also feel like problems I couldn't have avoided easily. My understanding is that for this to happen somebody in charge of a repo I've added promoted a package to stable before they promoted all of that package's dependencies. I'm not sure how I can avoid that other than being more restrictive about what repos I'm adding.

Now that I'm in this mess, how do I get out of it? Some of these packages are dependencies for other important packages such as ghostscript being used for printing. It seems like uninstalling and reinstalling is out of the question.

Please tell me that waiting for packages to promote out of unstable repos is not the only thing I can do.

Linux Mint 19.3 x64

EDIT: At request of the comments, I ran a few extra commands. Running `apt install` with each of the problem packages gave me similar output:

```
> apt install fontconfig fontconfig-config
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fontconfig : Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.13.0) but 2.12.6-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 fontconfig-config : Breaks: libfontconfig1 (< 2.13.0) but 2.12.6-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libfreerdp-client2-2 : Depends: libavcodec57 (>= 7:3.4.6) but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libavcodec-extra57 (>= 7:3.4.6) but it is not going to be installed
 libfreerdp2-2 : Depends: libavcodec57 (>= 7:3.4.6) but it is not going to be installed or
                          libavcodec-extra57 (>= 7:3.4.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I don't know much about `apt policy` but I ran it anyway:

```
> apt policy libfontconfig1 libfreetype6
libfontconfig1:
  Installed: 2.12.6-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.13.1-2ubuntu2~18.04.sav2
  Version table:
     2.13.1-2ubuntu2~18.04.sav2 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/multimedia/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.12.6-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libfreetype6:
  Installed: 2.8.1-2ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.8.1-2ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2.8.1-2ubuntu2 500
        500 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: What happens if you run `apt install ...` instead of `apt upgrade ...` (with the packages you’re trying to investigate)? What does `apt policy libfontconfig1 libfreetype6` output?

Comment: It's quite possible a few packages from an additional repository (which shouldn't really called "stable" if not official) made a few packets be upgraded to a newer version. I'd check the policy and available versions of those packages and consider downgrading them

Comment: looks I was wrong: weren't unduly upgraded. Just removing the offending ppa could maybe fix it.